# Find components attached to UBlueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I would just like to find the components attached to a blueprint..

Right now, I have a UProperty that exposes a blueprint to set..

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = "Associated Character")
UBlueprint*                                 BMoveBlueprint;
```

Then I receive an event for when this property is set..

```
void UTaskComponent::PostEditChangeChainProperty(FPropertyChangedChainEvent& PropertyChangedEvent) {


    Super::PostEditChangeProperty(PropertyChangedEvent);

    //Get the name of the property that was changed  
    FName PropertyName = (PropertyChangedEvent.Property != nullptr) ? PropertyChangedEvent.Property->GetFName() : NAME_None;

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Property changed: %s"), *PropertyName.ToString());

    if (PropertyName == GET_MEMBER_NAME_CHECKED(UTaskComponent, BMoveBlueprint)) {

        UBMoveComponent *BMoveComponent = (UBMoveComponent *) BMoveBlueprint->FindTemplateByName("BMove");   

    }
}
```

I would just like to find the components attached to the blueprint. This doesn't seem to work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindComponentByClass` ([UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/ACharacter/FindComponentByClass/index.html)):

```
if (PropertyName == GET_MEMBER_NAME_CHECKED(UTaskComponent, BMoveBlueprint)) 
{
    auto comp = Cast<UBMoveComponent*>(BMoveBlueprint->FindComponentByClass(UBMoveComponent::StaticClass());   
    if(comp)
    {
        //TODO (we have valid component, do something)
    }
}
```

You can use `Cast<>` even for `NULL` input, so it is safe to do it this way.

If you have more than one instance of some component, you can use following:

```
 TArray<UBMoveComponent*> comps;

 GetComponents(comps);
 if(comps.Num() > 0)
 {
     UBMoveComponent* FoundComp = comps[0];
        //do stuff with FoundComp
 }
```

(Code is based on Rama's code [UE Answers](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/126431/how-to-use-getcomponentbyclass-findcomponentbyclas.html)).

Comment: There isn't a FindComponentByClass method for UBlueprint. =[. I'm trying to find something similar... But I'm wondering if this is even a sensible thing to do since blueprints themselves aren't compiled and don't have instantiated members(?) What I'm really interested in is getting the blueprint that was dragged onto the scene. I think in that case the blueprint is compiled with all of its members and would serve me best if I could just get a handle on it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why `AActor* BMoveBlueprint;` is not good enough for you? Because if you are trying to get only a reference to a component, you don't need `UBlueprint`. Moreover I think, that you can cast *blueprint-based* actor to `UBlueprint*` later.